# Make sticky object stop being sticky

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, navigation

I'm about to make a portfolio for my exam. For that we have some articles we have to make for it. Therefore ive made a homepage, which shows the subjects that ive been writing about, and when you click on one of them, you come down to the article instantly. 
On the left side there is a new menu which is sat as sticky, and scrolls with the page. The menu only contains the subjects that im going through for that single

My problem is, that the menu KEEPS on scrolling with the page, when it should stop after the article has ended, so a new chapter menu can appear. How do I do that?

Edit: I was on my phone when i wrote it.. But here is the code for the MENU on HTML, CSS and Jquery

```js
  /*** Left Menu ***/
    var navLeftPos = $('#left_menu').offset().top;
    //console.log(navLeftPos)
    $(window).on('scroll', function () {
        console.log($(window).scrollTop())
        if (navTopPos <= $(window).scrollTop()) {
            $('#left_menu').addClass('left_menu')
        }
        if (navTopPos <= $(window).scrollTop() ) {
            $('#left_menu').addClass('left_menu')
        }
        else {
            $('#left_menu').removeClass('left_menu');
        }
    });
```

```css
/*** Menu sidebar ***/

div#wrapper div#underlayer div#ComputerensHistorie section#left_menu {
    float:left;
    width: 30%;
    padding: 1.5% 1.5% 1.5% 5%;
    background-color: #C4E1AC;
}

div#wrapper div#underlayer div#ComputerensHistorie section.left_menu {
    position: fixed;
    top: 105px;
    left: 0;
}

/***** Overskrift *****/

div#wrapper div#underlayer div#ComputerensHistorie section#left_menu h2 {
    font-family: Frank Ruhl Libre;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}

div#wrapper div#underlayer div#ComputerensHistorie section#left_menu svg {
    width: 60%;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

div#wrapper div#underlayer div#ComputerensHistorie section#left_menu svg .cls-1 {
    stroke-width: 0.5px;
}

/***** Animations understreg *****/

svg#understreg_et line#streg_tre {
    stroke: #3A8540;
    animation: backandforth 12s linear infinite;
}

svg#understreg_et line#streg_to {
    stroke: #fff;
    animation: backandforth 4s linear infinite;
}

svg#understreg_et line#streg_et {
    stroke: #245328;
    animation: backandforth 6s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes backandforth {
    0% {
        transform: scaleX(1);
    }
    25% {
        transform: scaleX(0.8)
    }
    50% {
        transform: scaleX(0.5);
    }
    80% {
        transform: scaleX(0.8);
    }
    100% {
        transform: scaleX(1);
    }
}

/**** Introduktion *****/

div#wrapper div#underlayer div#ComputerensHistorie section#left_menu p {
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 150%;
    padding-top: 15px;
    font-family: roboto;
}

/**** Navigation ****/

div#wrapper div#underlayer div#ComputerensHistorie section#left_menu nav {
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 150%;
    margin-top: 10%;
}

div#wrapper div#underlayer div#ComputerensHistorie section#left_menu nav ul {}

div#wrapper div#underlayer div#ComputerensHistorie section#left_menu nav ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
}

div#wrapper div#underlayer div#ComputerensHistorie section.left_menu nav ul li.links {
    margin-left: 20px;
    font-family: roboto;
}

div#wrapper div#underlayer div#ComputerensHistorie section#left_menu nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 150%;
    color: black;
    font-family: roboto;
    font-size: 0.9em;
}

div#wrapper div#underlayer div#ComputerensHistorie section#left_menu nav ul li a:hover {
    color: #3f824f;
}

div#wrapper div#underlayer div#ComputerensHistorie section#left_menu nav ul ul {
    margin-left: 15px;
}

div#wrapper div#underlayer div#ComputerensHistorie section#left_menu nav ul li h2 {
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-family: roboto;
    padding-left: 5px;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    width: auto;
}
```

```html
 <!-- Menu Left -->
                <section id="left_menu">
                    <h2>Computerens historie</h2>
                    <svg id="understreg_et" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 72 8"><defs><style>.cls-1{stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-width:2px;}</style></defs><title>streg</title><line id="streg_tre" class="cls-1" y1="1" x2="60" y2="1"/><line id="streg_to" class="cls-1" x1="72" y1="4" x2="29" y2="4"/><line id="streg_et" class="cls-1" x1="11" y1="7" x2="46" y2="7"/></svg>

                    <p>Vores dagligdag er konstant præget af den elektroniske verden, der omgiver os derhjemme, på gaden, arbejdet - alle steder!</p>

                    <p>Vi forsker hele tiden i hvordan vi kan optimere vores elektroniske viden, hvordan vi kan få det til at se smarter ud og ikke mindst mere praktisk.</p>

                    <p>Men hvordan startede det hele egentlig?</p>

                    <nav>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <h2>Kapitler</h2>
                            </li>
                            <li class="links"><a href="#underlayer">Lommeregneren som Grundsten</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#Antikythera">Antikythera - Den tidligste "computer"</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="links"><a href="#Stamfader">Stamfaderen</a></li>
                            <li class="links"><a href="DTC">Den tidlige computer</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#Zuse">Konrad Zuse</a>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="#Z3Computer">Z3 Computeren</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="links"><a href="">Referencer</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </section>
                <!-- Menu Slut -->
```

Comment: can you please post some code (or an image) that demonstrates the issue that you are having

Comment: Without showing us code, any answer would be a guess. [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please provide us with some code. Also tell us what you have tried yourself. Maybe some desired and current result images will be very helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

You will be counting the height or the article.

```
var h = $('articile').height();
```

And then You will tell your page to change the css of the element to relative after you scroll more then article's height

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  if(window).scrollTop() > h){
    $('navbar').css('position','relative');
  }
});
```

If you share some code I'll helping you better.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know what you are dealing with but this might help.

if you dont want it any loner :

```
$( ".target" ).hide();
```

if you have access to the code it self you can run this or if you are just a user and seems obsessed with the way it scrolls you can go to console on your browser and add that piece of code.

if you still want to keep it

```
var hieght = $('.target').height();
$(window).scroll(function(){
  if(window).scrollTop() > h){
    $('.stickty-menu').css('position','relative');
    // changes position  of sticky menu to relative to end scrolling 
  }
});
```